# Product ID in agent-ANYLOGIC

Tags: anylogic

I have created an agent ("Handsfree") in the agent I introduced parameter "WIRE". How do i make that parameter vary as simulation goes on so that it should automatically be set to either true or false so that i could assign the delay a specific time according to the parameter "WIRE".

Answer (score 0):

When does WIRE switch between true and false values? Is it based on time? If so, you can write a simple function to switch the initial value from true to false (or vice-versa). That function could also set the delay time in another parameter, "pDelayTime". Then, you'd call that function with an event at specified or random times (whatever is needed). The delay time in your block would need to be set to "pDelayTime".